# onLocationChanged is not being called

Tags: android, location, locationmanager

I am trying to show current location on the map but onLocationChanged is not being called.

```
@Override
public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
    Log.d("Called", "onLocationChanged");
    LatLng latLng = new LatLng(location.getLatitude(), location.getLongitude());
    MarkerOptions markerOptions = new MarkerOptions();
    markerOptions.position(latLng);
    markerOptions.title("Current Position");
    markerOptions.icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.defaultMarker(BitmapDescriptorFactory.HUE_MAGENTA));
    mMap.addMarker(markerOptions);
    mMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(latLng));
    mMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.zoomTo(11));
}
```

and here is my onCreate code

```
LocationManager lm = (LocationManager) getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
lm.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 1000, 0, this);
```

Comment: Do you have location enabled?

Comment: yes, location is enabled and also requested for permission

Answer (score 0):

Have you get both permissions

```
 requestPermissions({
        android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION,
        android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION,
    }, REQUESTPERM);
```

and also override `onRequestPermissionsResult` to handle grant/reject?

```
@Override
    public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, String[] permissions, int[] grantResults) {}
```